# Error time out al parsear con .visit()

Tags: java

Estoy parseando usando .visit() con este código:

```
String link = "Aquí iría la URL";                                    
Document doc = ScrapingUtils.visit(link, false);
```

El caso es que a veces por lo que sea no puede acceder a la página, y me envía un **error time out**. Me gustaría recoger cuándo ocurre esto para poder darle un valor concreto a las variables en las que se guardan los elementos que estoy extrayendo, pero no encuentro la forma.

Después de ese código sólo tengo un condicional if tal que así:

```
if (doc != null) {
   //código
else {
   //código
}
```

Lo único que se me ocurre es con un try/catch justo antes del condicional. Es decir:

```
String link = "Aquí iría la URL";                                    
Document doc = ScrapingUtils.visit(link, false);

try {
    if (doc != null) {
       //código
    else {
       //código
    }
catch () {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre algo como esto:

```
 try {
        if (doc != null) {
           //código
        else {
           //código
        }
      }
     catch (  TimeoutException exception) {
        throw new TimeoutException("Tiempo excedido: " + timeout + unit);
      }
```

y en el catch introduces los valores que quieras para las variables.

Comment: Gracias, pero no me deja poner TimeoutException, me sale el error "is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement". Cuando me da error read time-out, lanza ninguna excepción, con lo que entiendo que java está interpretando que ese error nunca se dará y de ahí que no me deje poner el try/catch

Comment: Pon en el encabezado de la función en la que esté `public T nombreFuncion() throws TimeoutException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException{`  a ver que tal.

Comment: Estoy siguiendo esta [Fuente](http://www.javased.com/index.php?api=java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException) para ayudarte, por si te vale mejor que mis explicaciones.

Comment: Gracias, pero me sigue marcando el mismo error.